# Aplicar formatação condicional individualmente a cada linha da planilha

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatação-condicional

Tenho uma planilha com datas e cidades. Preciso realçar (pintar de alguma cor) as cidades que estão repetidas em uma mesma data

Eu consigo aplicar formatação condicional para isso, mas fazer uma linha de cada vez demora muito tempo. Alguma dica?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: As cidades estão nas colunas B, C, D e E? Você quer comparar B com C, D e E reciprocamente de uma mesma linha ou quer comparar entre uma linha e outra?

Comment: Sim as cidades estão nas colunas B C D E F. Eu quero comparar somente dentro da mesma linha, ou seja, individualmente quando a cidade se repete em uma mesma data

Comment: Então não precisa comparar a data, mas sim se na linha existe cidade repetida, certo?

Comment: Exatamente. Eu sei fazer isso da seguinte forma:

formatação condicional > realçar regras das células > valores duplicados.....

O problema é fazer isso para um calendário que tem umas 500 linhas, um por um

Comment: Entendi... nesse caso veja se minha solução te ajuda! Foi o que pensei por agora.

Comment: No seu caso o Excel está em Inglês, né? Só substituir ai por **=IF(OR(** e vírgula ao invés de ponto e vírgula ok? Abs e boa sorte!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim como quase em todas as soluções em Excel, acredito que exista diversas maneiras para fazer isso. Pelo seu comentário, quer verificar numa mesma data, no caso em uma mesma linha se existe cidade repetida e colore (formata) a célula, então, o que vem à mente agora seria o seguinte?

1. Selecione a coluna *B* onde encontra-se a primeira cidade, selecionando a coluna toda, ou até onde tiver dados, iniciando na segunda linha para combinar com a fórmula:
   [image: selecao]
2. Vá na formatação condicional e clique em *Nova Regra*
   [image: nova_regra]
3. Selecione a última opção:
   [image: usar_formula]
4. Coloque a seguinte fórmula:

   ```
   =SE(OU($B2=$C2;$B2=$D2;$B2=$E2;$B2=$F2);VERDADEIRO;FALSO)
   ```
5. Clique em *Formatar* e selecione a formatação desejada, ficando, por exemplo, assim:
   [image: formata]

Formatado e com a fórmula.

Clique OK e OK novamente!

Pronto, a primeira coluna *B* estará funcionando sua formatação condicional.

Faça o mesmo para as colunas *C*, *D*, *E* e *F*, substituindo pelas fórmulas?

- Coluna *C*:

  ```
  =SE(OU($C2=$B2;$C2=$D2;$C2=$E2;$C2=$F2);VERDADEIRO;FALSO)
  ```
- Coluna *D*:

  ```
  =SE(OU($D2=$B2;$D2=$C2;$D2=$E2;$D2=$F2);VERDADEIRO;FALSO)
  ```
- Coluna *E*:

  ```
  =SE(OU($E2=$B2;$E2=$C2;$E2=$D2;$E2=$F2);VERDADEIRO;FALSO)
  ```
- Coluna *F*:

  ```
  =SE(OU($F2=$B2;$F2=$C2;$F2=$D2;$F2=$E2);VERDADEIRO;FALSO)
  ```

Lembrando sempre de selecionar a partir da linha que inicia na fórmula, no caso 2 ou ajuste a fórmula como desejar.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Bravo Evert, funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

Usa o filtro assim:

1.Vai em dados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Seleciona a célula do título e aperta em Filtro:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
3. Seleciona a data em questão e a cidade que você quer:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
4. Seleciona as células do filtro e pinta:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas eu preciso saber data por data quais cidades estão repetidas